# Proof probability distribution of number of particles seen in different basis connected by Bogoljubov transformation is Poissonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

Let we have two bases connected by Bogoljubov transformations. In the first basis, creation and annihilation operators are ($a,a^\dagger$) and in the second basis ($a',a'^\dagger$). They are connected by
\begin{equation}
a=\alpha a'-\beta^*a'^\dagger
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a^\dagger= -\beta a'+\alpha a'^\dagger
\end{equation}
And we have Bogoljubov identity
\begin{equation}
|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1
\end{equation}
We can get expectation of number of particle in second basis with respect to the first basis after a little calculation
\begin{equation}
\langle\hat{N}\rangle=\langle 0'|a^\dagger a|0'\rangle= \sum |\beta|^2
\end{equation}

> Is this mean number of particle that can be seen from the first basis?

*I have used component of $\alpha,\beta$ without explicitly writing $i,j$ etc.*

If so, the variance can be calculated as
\begin{equation}
\langle\hat{N}^2\rangle=\langle 0'|a^\dagger a a^\dagger a|0'\rangle
\end{equation}

> But it is giving answer $\sum( |2\beta|^4+|\beta|^2)$. But for Poissonian distribution it should be $\sum( |\beta|^4+|\beta|^2)$. Where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: you can give some references also

Comment: Do your operators satisfy bosonic or fermionic commutation relations? What are you summing over?

Comment: These satisfy Bosonic commutations. For simplicity, ignore the sum. If I would write component-wise then the sum would be important.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly, we have
$$\langle \hat{N}\rangle=\langle 0'|(-\beta a'+0)(0-\beta^* a^{\dagger  \prime})|0'\rangle=|\beta|^2.$$
We also have
$$\langle \hat{N}^2\rangle=\langle 0'|(-\beta a'+0)(\alpha a^\prime-\beta^* a^{\dagger  \prime})(-\beta a'+\alpha a^{\dagger\prime})(0-\beta^* a^{\dagger  \prime})|0'\rangle=|\beta|^2(\langle 0^\prime| \alpha^2 a^{\prime 2}a^{\dagger\prime 2}+|\beta|^2 a^{\prime}a^{\dagger\prime}a^{\prime}a^{\dagger\prime} |0^\prime\rangle)=2|\beta|^2\alpha^2+|\beta|^4.$$ This gives us the variance
$$\langle \hat{N}^2\rangle-\langle \hat{N}\rangle^2=2|\beta|^2\alpha^2=2|\beta|^4+2|\beta|^2,$$ so I am not sure how OP gets their result.

Comment: Yes there may have some problem or this is not Poisson distribution. For Poisson, mean and variance are equal. Here if use alpha^2=1+beta^2, it is not coming

Comment: Sorry, why should it be Poissonian? This is like a squeezing operation, which changes the statistics (in quantum optics language). For Hawking radiation, you know that the particles are thermal, not Poissonian (like tracing out one mode of a two-mode-squeezed vacuum state)

Comment: Yes you are right. It will not be Poissonian.